# Google Adsense Ad

Tags: adsense, publisher

A client asked me to create his ad with his Google publisher Id and Ad Id.

He told me to create this on a blog.
My problem is now that I don't know what he meant exactly because what I am used to is copying the code and pasting it.
So, can someone explain to me what he meant Does this require google API?

Let me know if this question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access his/her(your client's) google adsense account then :-

- Go to adsense website(login to your client's adsense account)>My
  Ads>New ad Unit

You will see something like this

[image]

- Now enter you ad unit name so that you can distinguish that ad from
  other and select the type of ad and all other data required.
- Now click on **Save and get code**. You will get an ad-code which will be having his/her Google publisher id.
- Just copy and past that ad-code to the relevant place(which you are already aware of)

If you can't get access to your client's account then tell him/her to follow the same give you the ad-code.

Comment: Thank you, I also thought of this. But since he insisted that I only need the publisher Id and Ad Id.

Comment: Well, he was not entirely wrong. In that case you can create the ad-code from your adsense account and replace your publisher id with his id. The only problem with this method is that you can not track this ad's performance.